# Close or Switch Tabs in Playwright/Python

Tags: python, browser, tabs, playwright, playwright-python

I'm doing an automation, at the time of download it opens a tab, sometimes it doesn't close automatically, so how can I close a tab in playwright using python?

Comment: Please add the code you tried?

Comment: @AlapanDas
I wanted to put code that would close only the currently open tab on the line with the red arrow.
https://prnt.sc/B6kiRTI10uNg

Comment: Did you try using `context.close()`?

Comment: @AlapanDas No, I'll try, but isn't there a playwright code that closes a tab?

Comment: @AlapanDas `context.close()` doesn't work, closes the browser, I wanted to close only the open tab.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make a code that closes only a specific tab!

```
all_pages = page.context.pages
await all_pages[1].close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).